# i want to get $_POST[variablex] but not posting from button click

Tags: php, post

i have a hidden element in my form, and when i want to get the posted value

```
$variable=$_POST["variablex"]
```

i dont get anything,on the other case when i do the post on **button (submit)** it does take a default value... HELP ???

```
<input type="hidden" name="variablex" id="variablex" value="555"  />
<a onclick=" document.getElementById('variablex').value='123';
document.getElementById('myform').submit();">123</a>
```

if anyone can send me link of example or tell me how to do it.

thanks :)

Comment: Your idea is when user click on a link to go to new page with posting that secret input ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is ok , try to see if there is the same id of a different element or the same name of forms, or maybe if u use master page check there if there is same name form or hidden variable, ive tested ur code and it works fine...greets

Comment: Yeah thanks that was the case, in my master page i had same named form that didnt had mu hidden variable...thx and sorry for the stupid noob mistake:) take care

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function onclickFunction()
{
    document.getElementById('variablex').value='123'; 
    document.getElementById('myform').submit();
}
</script>
<html>
<body>
<input type="hidden" name="variablex" id="variablex" value="555"  />
<a onclick="onclickFunction();">123</a>
</body>
</html>
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Answer with Jquery ..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#SOMEID").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("form#yourform").attr('action', $(this).attr('href')); /* If there are different links get its href and use it */
        $("#variablex").val($(this).text()); /* If you need to change the value of that input */
        $("form#yourform").submit();
    });
});
</script>
<form method="POST" id="yourform">
    <input type="hidden" name="variablex" id="variablex" value="555"  />
</form>
<a href="mypage.php" id="SOMEID">123</a>
```